# How to find the date of the first commit of files in git

Tags: git

Would there be a way to see the date of the first commit of a list of files, such that I could order them by that list?

*For context, I'm playing around with Node.JS, using it to create a simple blog where the "database" is actually a git repository.*

What I thought I'd try is to list out all the files in a particular directory, and then call something like this on each:

```
git log --format="format:%ci" --reverse [my file here]
```

This would output something like this:

```
2010-09-01 11:42:56 -0700
2010-09-22 12:17:19 -0700
2010-09-22 13:18:11 -0700
2011-03-05 00:11:19 -0800
2011-08-26 08:50:02 -0700
2011-08-26 08:51:50 -0700
```

Then, grab the first result and use that for ordering.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You may want to still play with node.js, but if you're thinking of using git for blogging, it already has an engine for doing this (without needing a host). Check out this post http://tom.preston-werner.com/2008/11/17/blogging-like-a-hacker.html.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can get what you want using the `--diff-filter` option to `git log`, selecting only files that have been added.  For example, you could parse the output of:

```
git log --format="format:%ci" --name-only --diff-filter=A
```

See the [documentation for `git log`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-log.html) for more on the different states understood by `--diff-filter`.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: fyi In some situations this command will output multiple commits(lines) which might not be what you want